# Rotating a matrix by 180 degrees anti-clockwise problems

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code that's supposed to rotate a matrix by 180 degrees anti-clockwise, but when the numbers of lines&columns is uneven, the middle line in the final matrix remains unchanged

```
    for (int index1 = 0; index1 <n / 2; index1++)
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < n; index2++)
            swap(mat[index1][index2], mat[n - index1 - 1][n - index2 - 1]);
```

Otherwise, the code works fine for an even number of lines and columns

Comment: Ok, so go back to the pencil and paper and see where your plan is flawed when it comes to an uneven number of lines and columns.

Comment: You'd do yourself a favor by using better names, like `row` or `r` instead of `index1` and `column` or `col` or `c` instead of `index2`. Then ask yourself: *Exactly what happens when you get to the middle row of a matrix with an odd number of rows?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to count amount of swaps, so that after half of the matrix done you can end it:

```
for (int index1 = 0, cntSwap = 0, maxSwap = (n*m) / 2; cntSwap < maxSwap; ++index1)
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < m && cntSwap < maxSwap; ++index2, ++cntSwap)
        std::swap(mat[index1][index2], mat[n - index1 - 1][m - index2 - 1]);
```